# How can I pass all required fields on testing updated method in a clean way?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing

I want to test my updating functionality. I can update a product on browser but I couldn't be able to pass the test.

Here my update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        Storage::delete($product->image_path);
        $product->update(['image_path' => request()->file('image')->store(auth()->id().'images', 'public')]);
    }
    $product->update(request()->validate([
        'name'      => 'required|string',
        'description' => 'required|max:255',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'compare_price' => 'required|numeric',
        'charge_tax' => 'boolean',
        'sku' =>[
        'required',
        'numeric',
         Rule::unique('products')->ignore($product->id),
         ],
        'inventory' => 'required|numeric',
        'track_inventory' => 'required|boolean',
        'width' => 'required|numeric',
        'height' => 'required|numeric',
        'depth' => 'required|numeric',
        'weight' => 'required|numeric',
        'weight_type' => 'required',
        'extra_shipping_fee' => 'required|numeric',
    ]));

    return redirect('/products'); 
}
```

Here my route:

```
Route::patch('/products/{product}', 'ProductsController@update');
```

Here my test:

```
/** @test * */
public function a_product_can_be_updated()
{
    $this->signIn();
    $product = create('App\Product', ['user_id' => auth()->id()]);
    $this->patch($product->path(), // how to pass all data in a short way?
    [
        'name' => 'changed name',
        'sku' => 32123,
    ]]);
    tap($product->fresh(), function ($product) {
        $this->assertEquals(32123, $product->sku);
        $this->assertEquals('changed name', $product->name);
    });
}
```

I know I must pass all data, but how can I make it in a clean way ? Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way would be to abstract the validation logic from the controller into a form request.

Take a look at the documentation here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests